# Windows hosting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> Error: system.security.securityexception: request for the permission of type 'system.security.permissions.securitypermission, mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

This error is show on run Mvc website.

customErrors is off, true level is full in web. Config file but there is some problem.

Website is: http://www.archin-modi.in

Answer (score 1):

if you set the following trust level in your web.config file, it should fix your error:

```
<system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
       <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
    </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Not working and after use this error:  <location allowOverride="false">